# Deleting linked list from the beginning-memory error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying the delete all the elements in a linked list in the beginning.
I used the following code, it seems like that it complied fine with ./a.out,
however, when I use valgrind ./a.out, it says there are memory errors.
Could you help me to fix the problem please?
Thank you!

```
  void List::emptyTheList()

if (head==NULL)
{
    cout<<"there is no elements in the list" <<endl;

}

else
{
DR *temp1;//DR is a class
temp1=head->getNext();
while(temp1!=NULL)
{
    free(head);
    head=temp1;
    temp1=head->getNext();
}

}
```

Comment: That code is not properly indented, nor will it compile. (There's no opening brace to the method.) Could you fix these issues? Then we'll have a good shot at answering the question.

Comment: Also, <pedant> "there is no elements in the list" should read "there are no elements in the list" if you want to be grammatically correct </pedant>

Comment: In terms of the logic flow of the code, it looks to me like you will never free the last element in the list? When 'head' is assigned to the last element of the list, temp1 will presumably be set to null by 'head->getNext()', which will cause the while loop to exit before you have free'd that last element (head). That's probably the memory leak / issue that Valgrind is complaining about. Can confirm when you provide a proper code sample as requested by sigpwned.

Comment: You may want to consider adding a pointer called next that points to the next element in the list to your DR class. That way instead of having to call the function getNext(), you could just use head->next to access the next node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Why am I seemingly the only person in this question that has a severe problem with a **C++** linked list that is using `malloc()` and `free()` for memory allocation? Clearly the object class `DR` has member functions. Chances are it has a constructor and a destructor as well.

Regarding your algorithm to clear a forward-linked list, the standard algorithm for doing so is this:

```
while (head)
{
    DR *temp1 = head;
    head = head->getNext();
    delete temp1;
}
```

This, assuming you are properly using C++ `operator new` (as you should be) for the allocation. If you're not, time to start doing so, otherwise neither constructors not destructors will be properly fired. If your allocation code looks like this:

```
DR *node = (DR *)malloc(sizeofDR));
```

or something similar, **stop it**. Do this instead:

```
DR *node = new DR(constructor parameters here).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have faults in the deletion part. Why don't you try this:

```
temp1=head;
while(temp1!=NULL)
{
    head=temp1;
    temp1=temp1->next;
    free(head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you can fix the problem simply by adding the line:

```
free(head);
```

after the end of 'while' loop. There are also better ways to re-structure this code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the problem consider the case when you have only one node.
It will never get freed since loop will never be entered.

If your code has been tested statically (or you have reviewed it on your own, you might get the problem before Valgrind).

In general, last node will never get freed.

This is the reason of problem.